# What does 'locations' refer to in GraphQL errors?

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql

I'm working through a GraphQL Node/Prisma server tutorial and encountered an error due to something wrong in my code.  I've solved the error but I want to understand the error message, in particular, what does `locations` refers to?  That is, I have a `location` of line 2, column 3, but line 2, column 3 of what?  The relevant method in my code (`signup`, in this case)?  Of my mutation?

```
// error message 
{
  "data": {
    "signup": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "secretOrPrivateKey must have a value",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "signup"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just like `path`, `locations` refers to where inside your GraphQL document the error occurred. You can see this for yourself using something like the [SWAPI GraphQL endpoint](https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql). We can trigger a validation error by requesting a field that doesn't exist:

```
{
  allFilmz
}
```

The resulting error has this `locations` array:

```
[
  {
    "line": 2,
    "column": 3
  }
]
```

That's because the offending field is on line 2, starting with column 3. If we instead send:

```
{allFilmz}
```

we get:

```
[
  {
    "line": 1,
    "column": 2
  }
]
```

Generally, the `path` of the error will be more informative than the `locations`, but the `path` won't exist when there are syntax errors in your document -- in those cases, the `locations` are the only thing you can use to track down where your syntax error occurred.

Word of caution if using GraphQL Playground -- unlike GraphiQL, Playground will strip out comments and format your request before sending it, so the `locations` may not match what you see in the Playground UI.